# Relate error from controller to field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Assume that I cannot add annotation of requierd to some filed in the model.

there is a way to raise and error from the controller to this specific field **on the right side of the field like if I use annotation...**

currently I use which put the error on top of the screen.

ModelState.AddModelError("", "User field is required);

Comment: Can you show your code and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same call, but replace the first parameter with the property name as a string you want to attach the error to:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("MyFieldWithError", "This is the error message");
```